# Multiple 7-segment displays connected to P1 of AT89C51

Tags: microcontroller, 7segmentdisplay, power-electronics

I want to connect three 7-segment displays on port-1 of AT89C51. The display unit has to show some number count. My question is:

1. What should be the refresh interval for TDM signals on this port so that the segments display different numbers at the same time, without flickering appearance?
2. Which darlington pair would be best suited in this case? Currently, I'm using CIL100 in darlington configuration. I don't want to use L293D or other packaged darlington arrays (for cost reasons).

Comment: Have you considered octal latches, or would that drive up some limited resource?

Comment: I already thought of that. Unfortunately, octal latches are hard to find in my place. Also, latches are more expensive than simple switching transistors. My design is going to be implemented for mass production. I don't think octal latches would be a good idea from cost perspective.

Comment: For flicker free operation the consensus seems to be a few hundred Hz but why do you need Darlingtons ? - a single transistor is quite capable of switching each digit.

Comment: Multiple discrete switching transistors are expected to be cheaper for mass-production than using a single octal latch device? What production process is this, please? Also, 74LV373 octal latch is around Rs.8 apiece retail in Mumbai so probably the same in Kolkata, and [even cheaper](http://www.ebay.com/itm/100-74LVC373A-OCTAL-D-TYPE-TRANSPARENT-LATCH-1-2-3-6Vcc-5V-IO-SSOP-20-SMD-SMT-/221247098124?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item33835acd0c) including delivery through eBay. *Question is based on invalid information*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What should be the refresh interval?*

Flicker perception is subjective, so there are no hard rules. Anything below 50Hz will noticeably flicker to most people.  Anything above 120Hz will be noticeable to very few people. Faster is even better. With only 21 LEDs you should have no trouble refreshing significantly faster and eliminating any perception of flicker.

*Which darlington pair would be best suited in this case?*

This is an invalid question. You have not provided any basis on which to decide. If these are ordinary 7 segment displays, I would use one of the many integrated solutions. If an IC is not available, I'd use whatever general purpose, ordinary transistor I had in my junk box, or whatever was cheapest from my suppliers. If these are not ordinary 7-segment displays, you need to specify them. If your issue is parts availability in your area, [this is a shopping question and is off-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).